# Converting an indefinite integral to definite integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, expression-manipulation

For example, I have the following integral expression:

```
g[x, y] = Integrate[f[x, y],x]
```

How can I modify the above expression to achieve the following definite integral:

```
h[x,y,a_,b_] = Integrate[f[x, y],{x,a,b}]
```

i.e. I am looking for a method to convert indefinite to definite integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us introduce the following rule:

```
Clear[k];

rule=Integrate[k_[x, y], x] -> Integrate[k[x, y], {x, a, b}];
```

Then

```
Integrate[f[x, y], x] /. rule
```

yields

[image]

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

You did not show a use case of why what you are doing is needed.

An option is to take advantage of Mathematica function name overloading.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
h[f_, x_, y_] := Integrate[f[x, y], x]
h[f_, x_, y_, a_, b_] := Integrate[f[x, y], {x, a, b}]
```

And now you can do

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I do not see a reason to make things more complicated, unless the above does not do what you wanted.